# How to resolve: parameter never used with T type while T itself is used?

Tags: java, generics, types, parameters, warnings

I am facing with a Java Warning ("Parameter myParameter is never used") on my generic method where I use type of the parameter (T) but not the parameter value itself. Can I avoid this warning without using SuppressWarnings annotation?

```
private <T extends MyInterface> MyGenericObject<T> init(Class<T> myParameter) {
   // lots of common code here ... and:
   return new MyGenericObject<T>();
}
```

The way I use this method at the moment:

```
MyGenericObject<MyClassA> aInstance = init(MyClassA.class);
MyGenericObject<MyClassB> bInstance = init(MyClassB.class);
```

Perhaps there must be a way to pass only the type to my method without parameter, but I cannot find the way for it. Could you please help me out with that?

Comment: Drop the parameter: `MyGenericObject<MyClassA> aInstance = init();`

Comment: I presume that `myMethod` is a typo.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Thanks for noting. Removed by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where I use type of the parameter (T)

But you don't need `myParameter` to provide you with `T`. It will work generically without it:

```
private <T extends MyInterface> MyGenericObject<T> init() {
   // lots of common code here ... and:
   return new MyGenericObject<T>();
}

// and invoke like:
MyGenericObject<MyClassA> aInstance = init();
MyGenericObject<MyClassB> bInstance = init();
```

A type parameter isn't really a "thing" you use. It's just an instruction to the compiler to make sure that all of the types which refer to `T` are compatible.

Comment: Silly me. Yes it was just as simple. Dropping the parameter simply and it works. Thanks for the quick answer!